# Remix Run Server Error, Error Boundary doesn't show

Tags: remix.run, react-error-boundary

i am building a web-app with remix-run and have a file `app/utils/session.server.ts` where i am accessing a sessionSecret from .env file.

```
const sessionSecret = process.env.SESSION_SECRET;
if (!sessionSecret) {
  throw new Error("SESSION_SECRET must be set");
}
```

For testing purposes i commented my sessionSecret out in my .env and expected the ErrorBoundary in my `root.tsx` to be thrown which looks like this:

```
export function ErrorBoundary({ error }: { error: Error }) {
  console.error(error);
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Oh no!</title>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2 className="text-red-600">{error?.message}</h2>
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, the website which i get back looks like this:

[image]

Does someone have a clue why it is not showing the expected ErrorBoundary?

Comment: I want to add that i think that this maybe happens because the Error is not thrown inside a loader or action function from a remix-route.

Comment: I'm noticing the same issue.  Did you ever figure this out?